# How to implement One time Verification(OTP) using Twilio SMS/Voice api

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, authentication, twilio

I am able to send SMS using twilio SMS APi

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put("From", fromNumber);
params.put("To", toNumber);
params.put("Body", "Bad news " + admins.get(toNumber) + ", take this");

try {
    // send an sms a call
    // ( This makes a POST request to the SMS/Messages resource)
    Sms sms = smsFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println("Success sending SMS: " + sms.getSid());
}
```

and want to implement One Time Password(OTP) based authentication in SPring MVC based web application. Mine view based on Thyme-leaf. I  got this link but this implementation is in PHP .https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/two-factor-authentication

Also tried using Node.js implemntation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install#using)in this case script executed but SMS sending is not happening

```
<script>
// Your accountSid and authToken from twilio.com/user/account
var accountSid = 'ACabdb218474d12644b16a5cfe891ce962';
var authToken = 'a4ba7b6ec6eb09aeccfbbb2143bc951d';
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
        to: '+918800989508',
        from:'+1 415-099-2671',
        body: 'Jenny please?! I love you 3',

    }, function(err, message) {
        process.stdout.write(message.sid);
    });

</script>
```

Any implementation for Java based application.

Comment: There is a twilio-java-sdk: https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install

Comment: @PatrickLC  I implemented same and able to send SMS. but want to implemnt same thing using Java script as i can generate no and send that generated no through SMS and verify  on UI in a fixed time period. can u suggest me some way to do it using java script?

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

We have an updated tutorial which shows how to implement this using Java:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/java/servlets

We're using Authy to validate the user, here's the code that handles this:

```
private Result sendApprovalRequest(User user) throws IOException {
    Parameters parameters = Parameters.builder()
            .addDetail("email", user.getEmail())
            .build();

    return client.sendApprovalRequest(
            user.getAuthyId(), "Request login to Twilio demo app", parameters);
}
```